# How to add XAttribute only if value is not null

Tags: c#, linq

I have following LINQ code to generate XML from a list of objects. When the AnalyteName is null or TestName is null, the following code will throw error. How can I add XAttribute only it the value is not null?

```
public static void StoreResult(List<LabPostResult> labPostResultList)
{
    var xml = new XElement("LabPostResult", labPostResultList.Select(x => new XElement("row",
                                     new XAttribute("PatientID", x.PatientID),
                                     new XAttribute("AnalyteName", x.AnalyteName),
                                     new XAttribute("TestName", x.Loinc)      
                                           )));
}
```

**Class**

```
public class LabPostResult
{
    public int PatientID { get; set; }
    public string AnalyteName { get; set; }
    public string TestName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just pass in null if the property is null:

```
var xml = new XElement("LabPostResult", labPostResultList.Select(x => new XElement("row",
                   new XAttribute("PatientID", x.PatientID),
                   x.AnalyteName != null ? new XAttribute("AnalyteName", x.AnalyteName) : null,
                   new XAttribute("TestName", x.Loinc)      
                                       )));
```

This way the attribute won't be created for objects which don't have `AnalyteName`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write an extension method. It will much cleaner.

```
    public static XElement ToXElement(this string content, XName name)
    {
        return content == null ? null : new XElement(name, content);
    }
```

And call it as below.

```
public static void StoreResult(List<LabPostResult> labPostResultList)
    {
        var xml = new XElement("LabPostResult", 
                                labPostResultList.Select(x => new XElement("row",
                                         new XAttribute("PatientID", x.PatientID),
                                         x.AnalyteName.ToXElement("AnalyteName"),
                                         x.Loinc.ToXElement("TestName")
                                               )));
    }
```

Comment: Works with XAttribute too!